# Ktor Serializer isn't seen by Android Studio (Serializer for class 'User' is not found.)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, serialization, ktor

I'm trying to use Ktor in my project. I made everything as it's written in documentation, but it doesn't work

Dependencies:

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.5.4"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.5.4"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:1.5.4"
```

HTTPClient and request:

```
val client = HttpClient {
    install(JsonFeature){
        serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
    }
    defaultRequest {
        url {
            protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
            host = "testtesttest.zapto.org"
        }
    }
}

suspend fun getUsersList() = client.get<User>{
    url("/users/list")
}
```

User class:

```
import com.kepler88d.icthack2app.model.enumerations.UserSpecialization
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class User(
    val id: Int,
    val password: String,
    val rating: Float,
    val specialization: UserSpecialization,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val profileDescription: String,
    val githubProfileLink: String,
    val projectIdList: MutableList<Int>,
    val replyIdList: MutableList<Int>,
    val tgId: String,
)
```

UserSpecialization class:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
enum class UserSpecialization {
    IOS_DEVELOPER, ANDROID_DEVELOPER, WEB_BACKEND_DEVELOPER, WEB_FRONTEND_DEVELOPER
}
```

When i'm trying to deserialize JSON into object it crashes with this error:

```
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'User' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.
```

The strange thing is that the enum class Android studio see as serializable, but data class doesn't

[enum class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVf3H.png)
[data class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI54X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this for Android but it may also work for ktor. At first, add this line to **dependencies** in the build project gradle:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.5.21"
```

Add also these to the build app gradle:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlinx-serialization'
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.2'
}
```

Please note version numbers might be different.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add plugin

```
id 'kotlinx-serialization'
```